# Ansible. How to insert a read/write ssh key to Bitbucket workspace?

Tags: git, ansible, bitbucket

I'm trying to automate ssh key creating and inserting them in Bitbucket workspace for fetch, pull and push operations.

I tried to use Ansible's `community.general.bitbucket_access_key`, but this tasks allows just read only keys. I found nothing about pull/push ssh keys in Ansible documentation.

Can someone point me the right way or some just workaround?

Comment: I am also very interested in this topic, did you find any solution for this